# How to use MS Access data objects in a .NET application to connect to SharePoint lists where OData Access is not available

Tags: .net, ms-access, sharepoint

My company is retiring MS Access, and has prohibited new development using this tool. I have data residing in a SharePoint list. OData is not currently configurable due to age and maintenance issues.

I am looking at the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access framework libraries and the Microsoft.SharePoint. framework libraries to try to determine if I can use this approach as an alternative way to connect to SharePoint lists using C# until OData connected services becomes available.

I would like to program the application to use OData by default, and when OData is not available switch to the equivalent of an Access DB Linked Table. This would mean that only if OData is not available an attempt will be made to use the "linked table." I do not want to create an Access database to be able to do this.

Am I barking up the wrong tree, or is this approach feasible?

Many thanks in anticipation.

Comment: But to use the interop Office libraries, then you need Access installed. So, if you not supposed to do future development with Access then why are you going to use the .net libraries that require Access to be installed? All of the SharePoint API's can be consumed as a web service, and quite sure you can even point Visual Studio to the appropriate web service (WSDL) to consume and  use SharePoint lists from .net. Strange that you suggest going away from Access and then ask about using Access as a inter op library from .net. So, consuming SharePoint tables (lists) is well supported from .net.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - thank you for your reply. You are correct in all the above. Our company has (I cannot explain reasons why) removed from our production servers owssvr.dll that provides the web services. These were restored on our UAT servers but alas our production farm is in an inconsistent state and cannot be remediated immediately.

If there are connection properties which can be used from the office suite then this solves a medium term issue for us. Long term web services is the way we will be going without compromise.